# Bounds for the covariance of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, covariance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive continuous random variable. I have noticed that

$$cov(\sqrt{X}, \sqrt{Y}) \leq cov(X,Y) \leq cov(Y^2, X^2).$$

I am wondering if there is a general rule that say that if (for example) $E[f(X)] < E[X]$ and $E[f(Y)] < E[Y]$ for some measurable function f defined on $[0, \infty)$, then we may be able to say that

$$cov(f(X), f(Y)) \leq cov(X,Y)?$$

Comment: The inequality ${\rm cov }\,(X,Y)\le {\rm cov}\,(X^2,Y^2)$ is not true. If $X=Y=aZ$ for $a>0$ then the inequality takes the form $a E(Z-EZ)^2\le a^2E(Z^2-EZ^2)^2$ which is not true for small values of $a$ if $E(Z-EZ)^2>0.$